How to provide a cancellation token to AzureOpenAI's ChatClient with streaming API
I have an Azure FunctionApp written in c# that makes call to Azure Open AI chat completion client.
In my function app, I am using "Azure.AI.OpenAI" library.
If I make API call to generate the response in its entirety and send back single response, It respects the cancellation token being passed. Here is a sample code.
Azure.AI.OpenAI.AzureOpenAIClient client = new AzureOpenAIClient(new Uri(openAIEndpoint), credential)
OpenAI.Chat.ChatClient chatClient = client.GetChatClient(deploymentName);
var response = await chatClient.CompleteChatAsync(prompt.Messages, prompt.Options, ct.Token);

However, If i make a call to stream partial results back as they are being generated, then the API does not respect the cancellation token. Or rather, I think that every call to streaming api to get the partial response resets the cancellation token.
Azure.AI.OpenAI.AzureOpenAIClient client = new AzureOpenAIClient(new Uri(openAIEndpoint), credential)
OpenAI.Chat.ChatClient chatClient = client.GetChatClient(deploymentName);
var responseBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
await foreach (StreamingChatCompletionUpdate completionUpdate in chatClient.CompleteChatStreamingAsync(prompt.Messages, prompt.Options, ct.Token))
 {
     foreach (ChatMessageContentPart content in completionUpdate.ContentUpdate)
     {
         responseBuilder.Append(content.Text);
     }
 }

What is the right way of using streaming api that respects the cancellation token?
How do I provide a cancellation token so that I'll be able to stop if the overall call is taking longer than the specified cancellation?
Adding complete method for reference
public async Task<string> CompletePromptAsync(double timeout, string promptData)
{
    // Generate prompt messages and options 
    List<ChatMessage> promptMessages = new();
    promptMessages.Add(new UserChatMessage("Please convert the 
input text data into JSON. Make sure to return JSON array with the elements extracted from the input data."));
promptMessages.Add(new UserChatMessage($"Here is the input data:\n{promptData}"));
ChatCompletionOptions promptOptions = new ChatCompletionOptions
{
 Temperature = 0.1
 FrequencyPenalty = 0,
 PresencePenalty = 0
 };

Azure.AI.OpenAI.AzureOpenAIClient _openAIClient = new AzureOpenAIClient(new Uri(openAIEndpoint), credential)
ChatClient chatClient = _openAIClient.GetChatClient(deployment);

using var ct = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));

// To Efficiently handle the larger response, build response using asynchronous streaming
var responseBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
await foreach (StreamingChatCompletionUpdate completionUpdate in chatClient.CompleteChatStreamingAsync(promptMessages, promptOptions, ct.Token))
{
    foreach (ChatMessageContentPart content in completionUpdate.ContentUpdate)
    {
        responseBuilder.Append(content.Text);
    }
}

return responseBuilder.ToString();
}


anyone know the right way of calling streaming api with cancellation?

Can you share the complete code in the question?

@DasariKamali Added the complete method above. Please let me know
